# Como llamar un XML como JSON en una API de PHP en Wordpress

Tags: php, json, xml

Tengo un problema, tengo una radio virtual que deseo que despliegue la información de la canción y del artista, dicha información la brinda un panel llamado SonicPanel. La web está alojada en WordPress la cual me permite agregar snippets de PHP, según el sonic panel el código es:

```
<?php
// This is an example PHP script to get the JSON data sent from the SonicPanel.

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$song = $data['song']; // Now Playing Song Arist - Title
$listeners = $data['listeners']; // Live Listners now listening to the radio.
$djstatus = $data['djstatus']; // true/false (string)
$djusername = $data['djusername']; // Online DJ username/false (string)
$art = $data['art']; // Now playing song cover art image, HD resolution.

// echo "Now Playing: $song <br><br> There are $listeners listeners <br> The album cover image url: $art";

print_r ($data); // Shows complete JSON encoded data.

// Any data provided on this page can be used as you like.
 ?>
```

Al colocarlo en el Wordpress entiendo que la variable `$data` obtiene la información a través de Json, pero originalmente viene en XML, en una URL.

Por lo que no tengo idea de como poder obtener el valor que me pide el `json_decode`

Agradecería mucho alguna ayuda. Gracias

Comment: ¿Y por qué quieres convertirlo a JSON cuando puedes manejarlo sin problemas como XML? No creo que sea una buena idea volver a manipular la respuesta que ya está en un determinado formato.

Comment: Porque el script que me da el Sonic Panel viene esperando un json, por ese motivo

Comment: No entiendo mucho realmente. ¿En el código que muestras, dónde está el XML? Hablas de una URL, pero tampoco se ve dicha URL. ¿Es una API? No expone esa API los datos también en formato JSON? Me chirría mucho tener que manosear los datos una vez recibidos, para convertirlos a otro formato.

Comment: @A.Cedano asumiendo ... creo que trata de decirte que el obtiene un XML pero otro software/plugin espera un json ... por ende tiene que convertir el XML a array y despues el array a Json ... creo que esa seria la forma de solucionarlo... pero es muy spyce ... no se si Sonic panel acepte XML... esperemos a ver que nos dice don diego.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 a mi me gusta ir a la raíz del problema. Como comenté  más arriba me chirría tener que convertir de un formato de archivo a otro cuando hoy día la mayoría de APIs que se respeten ofrecen posibilidad de respuestas tanto en `.json` como en `.xml`. Parece que [Sonic Panel se basa en el módulo WHMCS](https://kb.sonicpanel.com/article.php?id=15) el cual permite respuestas en formato json, como se puede ver en [este ejemplo](https://developers.whmcs.com/api/sample/), basta con indicarlo mediante el parámetro `responsetype`.

Comment: Si pero no es el escenarios que nos presenta, ahora es esto: `(Respuesta de tercero = XML)->(Servidor Wordpress XML a Array a JSON)->(Sonic Panel recibe JSON)`

Comment: @A.Cedano si la inicial (Respuesta de tercero) fuese en json no abria que hacer nada... como lo indicas es preferible no tocar conversiones entre formatos...